# Making one list from two calls in Razor

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm creating a simple site in Umbraco, using Razor.

I have a page, which may include several content "modules", which should be output on the page. The page might also have subpages – these should of course not be output on the page, neither should the content on these pages. To make it easier for the editor, the modules can be grouped together in an optional "Modules" folder under the page. The structure is thus:

– My Page
––– Content 1
––– Module folder
––– ––– Content 2
––– Subpage
––– ––– Content 3

The page "My Page" should thus list "Content 1" and "Content 2", while ignoring "Subpage" and its decendants.

This is done simply by creating two lists (CurrentPage.Children and CurrentPage.Modules.Children) and then concatenating them, as such:

```
// Retrieve all modules in subfolder "modules" ...
var modulesInFolder = CurrentPage.Modules.First().Children.Where("NodeTypeAlias != \"Page\"");

// Retrieve all modules found directly on page ... (i.e. child nodes except pages)
var modulesOnPage = CurrentPage.Children.Where("NodeTypeAlias != \"Page\"");

// Concatenate the two lists, so we can loop through them
var moduleList = modulesInFolder.Concat(modulesOnPage).ToList();
```

This works great – however, the "Modules" folder is optional. When it doesn't exist, nothing is output on the page at all. Presumably because "modulesInFolder" can not be declared. If I switch the two, it tells me "modulesOnPage does not conain a definition for 'Concat'".

I have tried a few different things, such as counting on the number of elements, and then defining 'moduleList' differently epending on the result, but to no avail. I also tried using one call, and simply listing all `Descendants()` but that also lists content from any subpages – unless I can pass something into the `Descendants()` method?

**How can I solve this in an elegant way elegantly?**

There is only one page type, and the modules folder has its own document type, but there are several different document types for the content modules.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following example to perhaps point you in a good direction. I was not clear if the collection of objects is what you ultimately wanted or not. What the example below will do is accept a parent node passed to the View and then write the values of properties to the page. I tried to do a few examples like what to do for things to ignore and cases where you may have different logic for a document type. I hope this gives you some guidance on your question.

```
@using umbraco.NodeFactory
@model Node
@{
    // For sake of example, we can state that Model is the My Page node you have
}
@foreach (var item in Model.GetChildNodes())
{
    // So lets go through all items that you mentioned
    @RenderSection(item)
}
@helper RenderSection(Node node)
{
    if (node.NodeTypeAlias != "Page")
    {
        // Pages don't get rendered
        return;
    }

    if (node.NodeTypeAlias == "Module")
    {
        @Html.Raw(node.GetProperty("TitleOfModule"))
    }

    // Output the content
    @Html.Raw(node.GetProperty("BodyContent"))

    // If you call render section again on the child nodes you can nest this structure to do things like if needed. Not sure
    //– My Page
    //––– Content 1
    //––– Module folder
    //––– ––– Content 2
    //––– ––– ––– Module folder
    //––– ––– ––– ––– Content 3
    //––– Subpage
    //––– ––– Content 3
    foreach (var subItem in node.GetChildNodes())
    {
        @RenderSection(subItem)
    }
}
```